# Difference in output for valid permutation of parenthesis using recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I wrote the code for valid permutation of parenthesis.It gives me correct output but making slight changes (written within /* */)makes it incorrect.Can someone please tell me what's the difference between the two?

```
void sol(int l,int r,string str)//l-left paran left,r-r paran left
{

    if(l==0&&r==0)
    {
        cout<<str<<endl;
        return;                          
    }

    if(l>0)
    {      
        /*
          str=str+'(';
          sol(l-1,r,str) ; */   //wrong output WHY?

        sol(l-1,r,str+'(') ;//correct output    
     }   


    if(r>l)
    {
       /*
          str=str+')';
          sol(l,r-1,str);*/

       sol(l,r-1,str+')');       
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you gave some examples of: the input you gave the function, the incorrect output you got, and what you expected the output to be instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you issue `str=str+'(';` on the first `if`, `str` is modified for the rest of the function, thus, when you reach second `if`, `str` is already `str+'('`.

Try with another variable to see if it works ok:

```
straux=str+'(';
sol(l-1,r,straux) ;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are making the changes in str then you have to remove them also after the recursion call.

Else pass the str as a parameter and changes are done in the local stack by which you are getting the correct output.

If you remove the '(' from str after the recursion call, then your change will also work correctly. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Code as Written**

The code in the first `if` block creates a temporary `string` object that contains `str + '('`. This temporary object is passed to `sol` recursively and then destroyed.

The code in the second `if` block then creates another temporary `string` object that contains `str + ')'`, and the same process is repeated.

**Commented Out Code**

With the commented out code, you're modifying `str`, and this modified value is carried into the second `if` statement. The first recursive call to `sol` is correct, but the second one passes `str + "()"` instead of `str + ')'`.